# Can the Watch Expression value be edited in eclipse>

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am developing an application for Android and and am using Eclipse. Is it possible to manually edit the value of a variable that is currently being watched, when we have hit a break point?

Answer (score 1):

Because watch expressions are not statements, they don't assign values back to your variables.  However, you can modify the state of your program by calling methods within your watch expressions that in turn modify fields.

You can manually edit your watch expressions by clicking on them in the Expressions view, but it doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Comment: If the watch is showing that a variable foobar=25 then I should be able to change the value to say 40, and from this point on the value of foobar becomes 40 wherever it occurs in the code. Visual Studio does have this functionality and I was wondering if a similar functionality does exist in Eclipse or not.

Comment: Before we go further, are you debugging C/C++, Java, or another language.  The core debug plugins create a model into which the language specific debuggers hook their implementations.  I know that the Java debugger treats watches as read-only evaluations of Java expressions.  Perhaps other language implementations do not.

Another thought is that maybe you're looking for Watchpoint functionality, which you set on variables and they break when the value is read/written.

Comment: I am developing Android Applications with Java.